# Java Jersey get POST array

Tags: arrays, post, jakarta-ee, jersey, jax-rs

I am trying to retrieve an array of numbers through POST, the raw data being sent to the server is:

```
bucket2=0&buckets%5B%5D=6&buckets%5B%5D=6&buckets%5B%5D=6&buckets%5B%5D=6&buckets%5B%5D=6&buckets%5B%5D=6&buckets%5B%5D=6&buckets%5B%5D=6&buckets%5B%5D=6&buckets%5B%5D=6&buckets%5B%5D=6&buckets%5B%5D=6&bucket1=0&currPlayer=0&bucketID=0
```

this contains an array buckets = [6, 6, 6, ...], from the javascript console:

```
Object { bucket2: 0, buckets: Array[12], bucket1: 0, currPlayer: 0 }
```

to post I use the following code:

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: baseUrl + "move",
    data: game,
    success: function(data) {
        // console.log(data);
        update(data); 
    }, error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
        console.log(errorThrown); 
    }
});
```

And my server code is:

```
@POST
@Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_FORM_URLENCODED)
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
@Path("/move")
public String move(@PathParam("currPlayer") int currPlayer,
                        @PathParam("bucket1") int bucket1,
                        @PathParam("bucket2") int bucket2,
                        @PathParam("buckets") List<Integer> buckets,
                        @PathParam("bucketID") int bucketID){

    System.out.println("currPlayer: " + currPlayer);
    System.out.println("bucket1: " + bucket1);
    System.out.println("bucket2: " + bucket2);
    System.out.println("buckets: " + buckets);
    System.out.println("bucketID: " + bucketID);
    return "";
}
```

With the server output being:

```
currPlayer: 0
bucket1: 0
bucket2: 0
buckets: []
bucketID: 0
```

Why doesn't it get the array values?

EDIT: I tried using @FormParam before creating this thread, but it still doesn't work

Answer (score 0):

You are consuming:

```
@Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_FORM_URLENCODED) //Meaning the content-type is `application/x-www-form-urlencoded`.
```

And yet, you are retrieving the parameters using `@PathParam`. For Content-Type `application/x-www-form-urlencoded`, you can read the parameters by using the `@FormParam` annotation.

---

Oh, your HTTP multi value form parameters must be of the form:

```
buckets=6&buckets=6
```

There is no need for `%5B%5D` in front of the `=` sign.

I hope this helps.

Comment: jQuery handles the converting, so not sure what to do about it. Thank you though.

Comment: figured it out, its because I was trying to get `@FormParam("buckets")`, when it should have been `@FormParam("buckets[]")`. Guess thats what the `%5B%5D` is.

Comment: Cool. Glad you figured it out.